# How to populate query in MongoDB and FastAPI?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, fastapi

I have a collection name "studio" and another collection name "user" and I am trying to make a one-to-many relationship in MongoDB and FastAPI.

- This is the document

[image]

- This is the route

```
@router.get("/{studio_id}")
async def read_studio(studio_id):
    studio_id = ObjectId(studio_id)
    studio = await studio_collection.find_one({"_id": studio_id})
    print(studio)
    return {"msg": "Success", "studio": studio}
```

I am getting the studio document successfully but I want to get details of the user of the document which means I want to populate user property.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried using[`"$lookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)?

Comment: tried that, bot working

Comment: If you show some example documents from each collection, and the desired output, I'm confident someone will provide a working aggregation pipeline.